# Shorewall is blocking everything. How to tweak it?

Tags: debian, routing, shorewall

I had used old DIR-400 router for years, but now it starts hanging and have problems. So I thought to replace it with a 2-ports motherboard with linux onboard, to be able to tweak and run some services.

I've installed Debian, configured /etc/network/interfaces, `isc-dhcp-server` worked as a charm - 10x faster than Dlink's DHCP; DNS was served by `dnsmasq`, but also i wanted a port forwarding, so i used iptables, and iptables-persistent (`iptables-save` command). Everything was good, before I thought I could do that better.

Problem was when I need to forward a port (or to disable it) - every time I had to switch the monitor, change keyboard, edit iptables, save new config. (SSH keys is a concept far away from normal user understanding, so not suitable for even trying to configure putty - i did sshd once, it lagged, and I promised - "never again!") So i installed shorewall and webmin. And the hell began!!!

First thing i noticed that dnsmasq not working. Okay, I had set up static ip `10.0.0.30` with dns `8.8.8.8` (on client machine in LAN) and proceed. Second thing is that shorewall is blocking everything! I installed it as was proposed in [two-interface 
configuration](http://shorewall.net/two-interface.htm) - via copying example and changing interfaces. That was done in a hope that I will get some defaults, free lan and restricted wan, and tweak that later through web interface. So to access webmin i had to forcibly stop shorewall, now i could access to 10.0.0.1:10000.. But that web interface is so extreme complicated, I just want a field like in a home-grade router "accept connetcions on port 80 and redirect it to internal ip 10.0.0.30". But nothing like that, extremely complicated web interface.

So everything is wreched now, iptables is overflooded with randomly generated stuff i cant even explain what is there.. I feel like i have to reinstall os from scratch and tweak it from command line. So questions are:

- How to fix or at least diagnose what's wrong with that malware, called "shorewall"?
- What are convenient(tweak "what is LAN and what is WAN" - login - tune web interface) user-friendly web interface for simple router-like tasks?

PS. I want to use Debian, or Debian-based router-specific distros, because I am alredy familiar with it. And I have little time to read tones of manuals, to learn new software or OS.